# If input is empty then assign None

Tags: python, if-statement

If input is empty or zero it should get None.

This is what has been attempted:

The `int` is necessary.

```
number = int(input('Type an integer: ') or None )
number = number if number != 0 else None 
print(number)
```

How to avoid this issue:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

Just change `None` to `'0'` in the line 1

So that, If the input is empty or zero, It is assigned as `None`

```py
number = int(input('Type an integer: ') or 0)
number = number if number != 0 else None 
print(number)
```

##### Explanation:

The first line is asking for the user input

And if the user input is an empty string (i.e., `''`) Python also sees an empty string as a boolean object (which is actually `False` for an empty string)

As the first case is `False` (i.e., the empty user input) according to Python, it automatically assigns the other value to the parameter of the `int` function as its because of the `or` keyword

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: How exactly the first line works? How come both 0 and '0' work the same in the first line?

Comment: it not a matter at all whether its a '0' or 0, at last it just gets converted into an integer as its inside the `int` function, i just wanted to denote that the string type of user input is only integers through my answer, i think nobody gonna get it i guess, nvm, u can even use it like `number = int(input('Type an integer: ') or 0)`

Comment: but what happens in the first line? The or '0' part means: or False? It works great but I don't understand it yet. Please explain the logic here. How it turns empty input to 0?

Comment: @user17589687 but you've wrote the or None part right? i thought u know it how it works

Comment: So if the input is empty it turns it to zero?

Comment: @user17589687 yes it does, r u expecting something other than this?

Comment: No as I said it works great but I am not sure I understand how if the input is empty it turns it to zero after reading your explanation. Any manual I can read on this boolean trick to understand it better?

Comment: @user17589687 i don't know any manual but a small note; any empty iterable item like string, list, set, etc, and even the integer 0 will have a boolean value of `False`, anything other than that like non-empty iterables, and even the integer -1 returns `True`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try-except`

```
try:
    number = int(input('Type an integer: '))
    if number == 0:
        number = None 
except ValueError:
    number = None
print(number)
```

Comment: It's worth adding what type of exception is being used here, rather than just a blanket exception

Comment: The OP just wanted to replace zero or empty input to ```None```.

Comment: Yes I know, but the original answer didn't have the ValueError exception type, so that's what I was referring to

Comment: In this case if a string is added in the input, the None will be assigned which is not correct.

Comment: How do you know it is not correct? The OP doesn't mention anything about that @user17589687

Comment: it says: If input is empty or zero it should get None. It doesn't mention anything about string input turning to None.

Answer (score 1):

There are three distinct operations here:

1. Read an input.
2. Convert that input to an `int`, if possible, or `0` if not.
3. Replace `0` with `None`.

Each of these should be done independently.

```
x = input("...")

try:
    number = int(x)
except ValueError:
    number = 0

if number == 0:
    number = None
```

It's not clear why `0` is so special that it should be replaced with a value of a different type.

Comment: It says: If input is empty or zero it should get None. In this case that you wrote, if it is a string in the input it will also turn it to None.

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between empty input and a non-integer string. If the OP want's to make that distinction, they can.